# Am I missing the correct geographic/coordinate information from Twitter API?

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, geolocation, geocoding, geo

There are a number of geo-related information when extracting information from Twitter API. Here is part of my codes...

```
placeHolder = []
placeHolder.append(tweet.author.name.encode('utf8'))

placeHolder.append(tweet.place)
placeHolder.append(tweet.user.location.encode('utf8'))
placeHolder.append(tweet.user.time_zone)
placeHolder.append(tweet.geo)
placeHolder.append(tweet.coordinates)
```

I have some specific questions hoping to get the answers here:

1) Am I collecting the right geographic location information? Esp. with tweet.geo and tweet.coordinates. Or is there any geographic information I am missing from my codes?

2) Which geo variable should I use to locate where the users published their tweets? "geo" or "coordinates"? Some people said "geo" is out-of-date, but when I look at them in the data, they are simply the same except the longitude and latitude flipped around.

3) I just looked at my data, it seems only about 0.35% of my sample tweets contain information on the "geo"/"coordinates" variable, is it too low or around normal? I found that "tweet.user.location" has way more information, but not standardized, what is the best way to incorporate all of these geo information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1) Am I collecting the right geographic location information? Esp. with tweet.geo and tweet.coordinates. Or is there any geographic information I am missing from my codes?*

Assuming by right geographic location being where the person was at the time of tweet then `tweet.place`, `tweet.geo`, and `tweet.coordinates` are what you're looking for. Anyone under `user.*` is defined by the user not twitter.

*2) Which geo variable should I use to locate where the users published their tweets? "geo" or "coordinates"? Some people said "geo" is out-of-date, but when I look at them in the data, they are simply the same except the longitude and latitude flipped around.*

For that one I would also recommend `tweet.coordinates` for two reasons: a) it's the official geocoded field according to twitter, b) it's in proper geojson format (long, lat)

*3) I just looked at my data, it seems only about 0.35% of my sample tweets contain information on the "geo"/"coordinates" variable, is it too low or around normal? I found that "tweet.user.location" has way more information, but not standardized, what is the best way to incorporate all of these geo information?*

Like I said in "1)" anything under `user.*` is user defined. So for example you can say you're from Mars, but if you have geo enabled and you tweet, `tweet.coordinates` will give the true location (most likely not Mars).

That percentage is low, but it's hard to say. It all depends on the location you're defining, if you're talking about the whole world tweet there's no specific number you can base that off of. From experience, I can tell you that (if no word filter is included) the US has roughly 10% geo information for tweets. The reason I say no word filter is because once you search tweets based off of words you're including biased data to your system.